# Meu formulário só envia o email para o próprio servidor

Tags: php, email

Tenho um formulário que envia e-mail normalmente, mas quando coloquei a opção de enviar uma cópia para o e-mail do cliente, ele não envia. Fiz vários testes e descobri que ele não envia e-mail para nenhuma conta que não seja do próprio servidor.
Ou seja, estou recebendo os pedidos dos cliente, mas os clientes não estão recebendo uma cópia, como deveria receber. O que eu faço?

```
$to = $email;
$subject = "Seu pedido ao restaurante BARDANA - Número do Pedido: 00".$gerador;

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$headers .= "From: $email\r\n"; // remetente
$headers .= 'Cc: ramos@bardananatural.com.br' . "\r\n";


//mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {

}
```

Na parte do `$to` era para ele enviar uma copia para o e-mail cadastrado no formulário (`$email`)

Agradeço a atenção!

Comment: Quando for para complementar uma pergunta que não teve resultados, edite-a em vez de fazê-la novamente. À propósito, repetindo o comentário já feito na sua pergunta original, você continua não pondo os `< >` que faltam nos endereços de email.

Comment: Oi Bacco, eu até tentei apagar aquela questão, mas sou novo aqui e não vi como fazer isso. Eu coloquei <> mas mesmo assim não enviou.

Comment: E o mais estranho que no e-mail que esse pedido vai, aparece no cabeçalho direitinho o e-mail do cliente como cópia, mas que acaba não sendo enviado. :(

Comment: Como não tem resposta nenhuma lá, pode clicar em editar embaixo dela e acrescentar os detalhes que precisar. O próprio fato de editar faz com que ela volte pra fila de postagens com atividade, atraindo mais atenção. Aliás, não serve como resposta para a pergunta, mas serve como teste: chamar a função mail duas vezes, uma com cada endereço.

Answer (score 0):

Tente implementar seu sistema de disparo de emails com o **[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)**.
Depois de baixar e configurar em sua área de trabalho, faça algo mais ou menos assim para disparar estes emails.

```
<?php

require "../PHPMailerAutoload.php";

// Cria uma noa instância de PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer;
// Dados de Quem envia
$mail->setFrom($email, "Nome de quem envia");
// Se quiser que as respostas sejam enviadas para outro email
$mail->addReplyTo($email, "Responda para");
// Dados de Quem recebe
$mail->addAddress($email);
// Cópia de outro email que receberá
$mail->addCC("ramos@bardananatural.com.br");
// Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Subject = "Seu pedido ao restaurante BARDANA - Número do Pedido: 00" .$gerador;
// Mensagem do formulário em HTML
$mail->msgHTML("<b>Mensagem de $nome</b><br /><br />$message");
// Mensagem alternativa para leitores de email que não suportam HTML
$mail->AltBody = "Esta mensagem está em HTML, use um leitor de emails compatível.";
// Envia a mensagem e verifica se deu certo
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Deu erro ao enviar: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Mensagem enviada!";
}
```

Espero que resolva, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Percebi que você usa o método msgHTML invés do método Body para o conteúdo que contem, ou pode conter, HTML. Nunca tinha visto esse método antes e acredito que muitos também não, até porque, no próprio GitHub do PHPMailer, eles ensinam usar o Body e não fazem nenhuma menção ao msgHTML. Poderia nos esclarecer a diferença entre os dois métodos?

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira , na classe que está hospedada no GitHub tem o exemplo da forma como encontra-se na publicação: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/sendmail.phps